# Link abrindo em uma nova janela

Tags: html, link

Tenho uma imagem, que é um link para a página index(home). Acontece que quando eu clico no link, o navegador abre uma outra janela, **mas deveria abrir na mesma**.

Como eu faço para resolver isto? Abaixo meu código:

```html
<a href="/Home/Index/" title="Twitter"
  target="_blank"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logo-agaxtur.jpg")" class="logo" />
</a>
```

Comment: Você não inseriu seu código

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei o problema, que seria por causa do atributo `target` que define quando um elemento HTML `<a>` há um destino personalizado, do qual, no meu caso, possuía o valor `_blank`. Bastou a remoção do atributo, para que o link voltasse a funcionar normalmente.